# How do you use SVG's on Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

The flutter_web docos say to that dart:svg is ported, but how do you use that with the flutter asset / widget system?

Comment: I dont know how to use dart:svg but I created an example project that uses HtmlElementView to show svg on mobile and on web: https://github.com/masewo/flutter_svg_web_example

Comment: Thank you :) flutter_svg it's an option but it only work with android/iOS, websafe_svg also work with web but not work as expect on firefox.

Comment: It looks like the Firefox issue in websafe_svg has been fixed recently and it should be safe to use it now. https://github.com/peiffer-innovations/websafe_svg/issues/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) version 1.0.0 is out since Dec 2, 2021 including web support. So there is no longer a blocker to use svg images inside a Flutter project.

Answer (score 16):

Honestly the best solution I've found is to load the image over a network for the web. Store the asset on a CDN somewhere, get it from the CDN on the web version, and retrieve it from your assets locally on iOS/Android.

I've created a `CrossPlatformSvg` widget using this library: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg, something like:

```
class CrossPlatformSvg {
  static Widget asset(
    String assetPath, {
    double width,
    double height,
    BoxFit fit = BoxFit.contain,
    Color color,
    alignment = Alignment.center,
    String semanticsLabel,
  }) {
    // `kIsWeb` is a special Flutter variable that just exists
    // Returns true if we're on web, false for mobile
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return Image.network(
        assetPath,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        fit: fit,
        color: color,
        alignment: alignment,
      );
    } else {
      return SvgPicture.network(
        assetPath,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        fit: fit,
        color: color,
        alignment: alignment,
        placeholderBuilder: (_) => Container(
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
          child: CircularIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's even works if you place your svg under the assets catalog and call Image.network

Comment: On the web in debug mode, I get the following error. So I don't think Image.network supports SVG. Tested on 1.26.0-8.0.pre • channel dev
The following ImageCodecException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed to decode image data.

Comment: It seems flutter dropped svg support, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74489

Answer (score 8):

@aterenshkov's approach worked for me (see comments under Jack's answer). Here are the details to implement...

**iOS / Android**

```
child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/yourimage.svg')
```

**Web**

```
// remove assets folder reference
child: SvgPicture.asset('yourimage.svg')
```

**Combine these 2 together...**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'; // provides kIsWeb property
...
child: kIsWeb ? SvgPicture.asset('yourimage.svg') : SvgPicture.asset('assets/yourimage.svg')
```

Answer (score 6):

My Flutter web app would render SVGs in a desktop web browser but not a mobile web browser using [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg).  I found it necessary to build with canvaskit support in order for SVGs to render on mobile:

```
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit
```

However, the [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) state that canvaskit adds about 2MB in download size, which was a dealbreaker for me.  Sad to say, but I will be using raster images until this is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

@RumbleFish has nicely but using ternary operation at many can make the code messy.

My approach to this is:

- Create an Extension Function on String to replace `assets/` from the path.

> ```
> extension ForWeb on String {
>   String forWeb({required bool web}) => web ? this.replaceFirst('assets/','') : this;
> }
> ```

- Now in code:

> `SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/logo.png".forWeb(web: kIsWeb));`