# Image URI not loading in flutter ios

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-ios

I'm creating a native app where I'm using image `URI` instead of png or jpg image just to reduce the size. But the issue is that the image URI is not loading/showing in ios. I tried on android and the web it's working.

Here is the code

```
//Image URI
var _hello_Image_Uri =       "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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";


        Container(
              width: 120,
              height: 120,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
              ),
              child: Image.network(_hello_Image_Uri),
            )
```

where

```
Image.network(_hello_Image_Uri),
```

Issue

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file: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
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Image.network` is for images obtained through a network as the name implies. If you look at the implementation of `Image.network`, you'll find that it will attempt to make a `GET` request with an HTTP client. Since there is no host in the URI string you show, this request fails as expected. [Source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart).

There's a lot going wrong with what you're trying to do here. Reducing image size by using SVG is a good idea since I guess you had a vector source, but understand that Flutter does not native support for SVG. It may work on the web when using canvaskit, but not for other platforms. You will need to use the [`flutter_svg`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package and can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57174617/how-do-you-use-svgs-on-flutter-web) SO answer to find a way to make it work on web as well. I would use the `SvgPicture.string` or `SvgPicture.asset` constructors instead of what they show in their answer so that there are no unecessary network requests. This may be more trouble than it's worth and support will be more flakey than using a raster image, but that's up to you. Also be aware that using this package and the canvaskit renderer will increase overall application size, which may not be worth it for only a few images.

Code from linked answer:

> ```
> class CrossPlatformSvg {
>   static Widget asset(
>     String assetPath, {
>     double width,
>     double height,
>     BoxFit fit = BoxFit.contain,
>     Color color,
>     alignment = Alignment.center,
>     String semanticsLabel,
>   }) {
>     // `kIsWeb` is a special Flutter variable that just exists
>     // Returns true if we're on web, false for mobile
>     if (kIsWeb) {
>       return Image.network(
>         assetPath,
>         width: width,
>         height: height,
>         fit: fit,
>         color: color,
>         alignment: alignment,
>       );
>     } else {
>       return SvgPicture.network(
>         assetPath,
>         width: width,
>         height: height,
>         fit: fit,
>         color: color,
>         alignment: alignment,
>         placeholderBuilder: (_) => Container(
>           width: 30,
>           height: 30,
>           padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
>           child: CircularIndicator(),
>         ),
>       );
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

---

Your current attempt also unnecessarily *increases* the amount of data that needs to be stored because you're using a base64 encoded string. Base64 encoding will increase the amount of data that needs to be stored by ~1.5 times, which goes against your intention of reducing size.